# How to check a single checkbox using ternary operator when multiple checkbox exist?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ternary-operator

I do have the following HTML

```
<td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="PrevPay" checked="@(item.BSBreakTPayType.Value==322 ? "checked":"")" />
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Fullpay" checked="@(item.BSBreakTPayType.Value==323 ? "checked" : "") "/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Halfpay" checked="@(item.BSBreakTPayType.Value==324 ? "checked" : "")" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Nopay" checked="@(item.BSBreakTPayType.Value==325 ? "checked" : "")"/>
</td>
```

Now here I need to display all the checkboxes and need to check only the checkbox which contains a value. The above code check's all the checkboxes. Am I wrong somewhere please correct me. Thanks

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="PrevPay" '@(item.BSBreakTPayType.Value==322 ? "checked":"")' />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put it following way for each checkbox, when `checked` attribute is rendered, checkbox gets checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="PrevPay" 
       @(item.BSBreakTPayType.Value==322 ? Html.Raw("checked=\"checked\"").ToHtmlString() :"") />
```

Comment: Amazing I got it but please do edit and say <input type="checkbox" id="PrevPay"  @(item.BSBreakTPayType.Value==322 ? Html.Raw("checked=\"checked\"").ToHtmlString() :"") />  . I need to convert it to ToHtmlString() since, I got an error saying: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined.......... and I modify as I described  above. Thank plz do modify your answer and I will mark it as accepted.